# SQL Joins, seleccionar datos de distintas tablas

Tags: php, sql, join

Estoy teniendo problemas al seleccionar datos de diferentes tablas, les explico.

Tengo tres tablas y ocupo ciertos datos de cada una de ellas:

```
usuarios AS u
u.id   u.usuario

proyecto_emp AS p
p.id_proyecto   p.us_id   p.rol

roles AS r
r.id   r.rol
```

Las relaciones son así:

```
u.id = p.us_id
p.rol = r.id
```

Necesito colocar los datos `u.usuario` y `r.rol` dentro de una tabla en `html`, eso ya lo tengo hecho pero me coloca todos los usuarios y entonces necesito poner como parámetro que sólo me de los usuarios que están dentro de un proyecto en específico: `$proyecto_id`.

Para eso quiero colocar un `WHERE p.id_proyecto = $proyecto_id` pero no sé de que forma hacerlo, espero me haya dado a entender y les agradezco la ayuda.

Aquí les dejo el código con el que lo estoy intentando:

```
$data = $conex->getAll("SELECT u.usuario, r.rol
    FROM Usuarios u WHERE 'id_proyecto = '$proyecto_id''
    LEFT JOIN proyecto_emp pe ON u.id = pe.us_id
    LEFT JOIN Roles r ON pe.rol = r.id");
```

Pd: es la primera vez que uso Joins.

Comment: Cuando usas JOIN, también el `WHERE` va al final. La consulta sería: `SELECT u.usuario, r.rol
    FROM Usuarios u 
    LEFT JOIN proyecto_emp pe ON u.id = pe.us_id
    LEFT JOIN Roles r ON pe.rol = r.id WHERE pe.id_proyecto = $proyecto_id` Pero, para evitar [Inyeccion SQL](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/18232/29967) usa consultas preparadas. Algo así: `SELECT u.usuario, r.rol
    FROM Usuarios u 
    LEFT JOIN proyecto_emp pe ON u.id = pe.us_id
    LEFT JOIN Roles r ON pe.rol = r.id WHERE pe.id_proyecto = ?`  y luego pasas aparte el valor `$proyecto_id`

Comment: Por ahí andaba... muchas gracias, era lo que necesitaba, ¿podrías ponerlo como respuesta para aceptarla?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cuando usas JOIN, también el `WHERE` va al final.

La consulta sería:

```
SELECT u.usuario, r.rol 
FROM Usuarios u 
LEFT JOIN proyecto_emp pe ON u.id = pe.us_id 
LEFT JOIN Roles r ON pe.rol = r.id 
WHERE pe.id_proyecto = $proyecto_id;
```

Pero, para evitar [Inyeccion SQL](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/18232/29967) usa consultas preparadas.

Sea usando marcadores de nombre (ver 1er ejemplo más abajo):

```
SELECT u.usuario, r.rol 
FROM Usuarios u 
LEFT JOIN proyecto_emp pe ON u.id = pe.us_id 
LEFT JOIN Roles r ON pe.rol = r.id 
WHERE pe.id_proyecto = :id_proyecto;
```

O usando marcadores de posición `?` (ver 2º ejemplo más abajo):

```
SELECT u.usuario, r.rol 
FROM Usuarios u 
LEFT JOIN proyecto_emp pe ON u.id = pe.us_id 
LEFT JOIN Roles r ON pe.rol = r.id 
WHERE pe.id_proyecto = ?;
```

Y luego pasas aparte el valor `$proyecto_id`.

Aquí tienes dos ejemplos de código funcionando que implementan consultas preparadas:

- 1er ejemplo: [usando PDO](http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/siwp-53q9)
- 2do ejemplo: [usando MySQLi](http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/ijuw-wrq9)

Answer (score 0):

con este sql te va a funcionar

```
SELECT u.usuario, r.rol FROM Usuarios u LEFT JOIN proyecto_emp pe ON u.id = pe.us_id LEFT JOIN Roles r ON pe.rol = r.id WHERE pe.id_proyecto = $proyecto_id
```

Saludos.